# Should the [not-a-robot] MSO tag be renamed to [not-a-robot-badge]?

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, tags, retag-request

We just had [a question](/q/419638/15497888) here on MSO where the [not-a-robot](/questions/tagged/not-a-robot) tag [was used](/revisions/419638/1) to refer to a CAPTCHA dialogue ([captcha](/questions/tagged/captcha)). Which is a fair misunderstanding because the CAPTCHA input button has the label "I'm not a robot".

Should we rename the [not-a-robot](/questions/tagged/not-a-robot) tag to [not-a-robot-badge](/questions/tagged/not-a-robot-badge)?

This would also put it in line with the other specific badge tags:

- [tumbleweed-badge](/questions/tagged/tumbleweed-badge)
- [electorate-badge](/questions/tagged/electorate-badge)
- [convention-badge](/questions/tagged/convention-badge)
- [yearling-badge](/questions/tagged/yearling-badge)
- [deputy-badge](/questions/tagged/deputy-badge)
- [marshal-badge](/questions/tagged/marshal-badge)
- [mortarboard-badge](/questions/tagged/mortarboard-badge)
- [epic-badge](/questions/tagged/epic-badge)
- [legendary-badge](/questions/tagged/legendary-badge)